# C address ranges of variables

Tags: c, unix, memory

How can I print/find the address ranges for all kind of variables (global, local, static, etc). Are the ranges defined by any standard, or can I get them with a tool, or with a bash command? Thanks for any help :)

Comment: What is "address range"?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Write a script to help debug a program at runtime? Write a cheat trainer? Build a higher-level emulator?

Comment: the address range within the memory. or is it like, for example: stack size is 8MB (empty) so first element is `0` and last element is first element + 8MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start address of a variable is provided by the *address-of* operator `&`. The end address can be determined by adding its size to the start address less one - bearing in mind that in pointer arithmetic adding 1 to a pointer increments the address by the size of the object so, it is simplest to cast the pointer to a `char*` because `sizeof(char) == 1`.

So:

```
start = &var ;
end = (char*)&var + sizeof(var) - 1 ;
```

A suitable macro for displaying this information might be:

```
#define SHOW_ADDRESS_RANGE( var ) printf( #var"\t %p - %p  %u bytes.\n", &var, (char*)&var + sizeof(var) - 1 , sizeof(var) )
```

For example the following test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SHOW_ADDRESS_RANGE( var ) printf( #var"\t %p - %p  %u bytes.\n", &var, (char*)&var + sizeof(var) - 1 , sizeof(var) )

int a_global_int ;

int main(void) 
{
    static a_static_int ;
    char char_array_10[10] ;
    int int_array_16[16] ;
    int integer ;
    char character ;
    long long long_long ;
    struct
    {
        int x ;
        int y ;
        char array[10] ;
    } a_structure ;

    SHOW_ADDRESS_RANGE( a_global_int ) ;
    SHOW_ADDRESS_RANGE( a_static_int ) ;
    SHOW_ADDRESS_RANGE( char_array_10 ) ;
    SHOW_ADDRESS_RANGE( int_array_16 ) ;
    SHOW_ADDRESS_RANGE( integer ) ;
    SHOW_ADDRESS_RANGE( character ) ;
    SHOW_ADDRESS_RANGE( long_long ) ;
    SHOW_ADDRESS_RANGE( a_structure ) ;

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs (for example - your addresses will probably be different, as may the data type sizes and structure alignment and packing):

```
a_global_int     0x8049948 - 0x804994b  4 bytes.
a_static_int     0x8049944 - 0x8049947  4 bytes.
char_array_10    0xbf856502 - 0xbf85650b  10 bytes.
int_array_16     0xbf856520 - 0xbf85655f  64 bytes.
integer  0xbf8564f4 - 0xbf8564f7  4 bytes.
character    0xbf8564f3 - 0xbf8564f3  1 bytes.
long_long    0xbf8564f8 - 0xbf8564ff  8 bytes.
a_structure  0xbf85650c - 0xbf85651f  20 bytes.
```

---

In the light of comments, it seems you may be asking something different than that addressed by my answer above:

Static data allocation is known at build time and can be reported by your linker in the map file. A multi-threaded process has one stack per thread, and the thread stacks may be allocated from the heap at run-time. The linker addresses will be offsets to the process's load address which is determined at run time by the OS loader.  In a modern desktop or server OS, the addresses themselves with be virtual rather than physical.  The details are platform specific, the precise details for Unix may differ from what I have described.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I print/find the address ranges for all kind of variables (global, local, static, etc).

Local variables are generally stored on the stack—meaning they have a different address each time the function is called, and no address in between function calls—or in registers—meaning they don't have an address at all.

Global and static variables are basically the same thing after the linker is done with them. They may have a fixed address, or a fixed offset from some segment address that's only available at runtime, or an entry in a relocation table that isn't specified until runtime. On some Unix platforms, objects specify default base addresses (or per-segment base addresses) and are only relocated if they conflict with something else (meaning executables are usually not relocated, shared libraries may or may not be); on other platforms, everything is always relocated no matter what (as a security feature).

Also, variables may or may not have public symbols, depending on how you compiled and linked a program or shared object. If they do, you can generally look up the address/offset/relocation entry using a tool that's part of your compiler toolchain, like `nm` or `objtool`; if they don't, there's nothing to look up.

> Are the ranges defined by any standard

Not any Unix (or POSIX/SuS) standard. If you ask about a more specific platform, like linux with glibc2.3+ on x86_64 using the standard ABI, there might be a partial answer, but that answer will be different for each platform.

> or can I get them with a tool, or with a bash command

There's no built-in bash command, but, as mentioned above, your combination of platform and compiler toolchain may have a tool that can get you some of the information you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you link your application, you need to create a linker map file.  The switch to do this depends upon the linker you are using. That will show how the memory has been allocated.